# Extend pip package with other packages

Tags: python, pip

Normally you just install any package like this `pip install SomePackage`, but for some packages I've seen `pip install SomePackage[anotherPackage]` or using `SomePackage[anotherPackage,yetAnother]` so it effectively extends some functionality in `SomePackage` without causing bloat.

How do you achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's known as [extras](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) in setuptools nomenclature

Quoting official docs:

> Sometimes a project has “recommended” dependencies, that are not
>   required for all uses of the project. For example, a project might
>   offer optional PDF output if ReportLab is installed, and
>   reStructuredText support if docutils is installed. These optional
>   features are called “extras”, and setuptools allows you to define
>   their requirements as well. In this way, other projects that require
>   these optional features can force the additional requirements to be
>   installed, by naming the desired extras in their install_requires.
>
> For example, let’s say that Project A offers optional PDF and reST
>   support:
>
> ```
> setup(
>     name="Project-A",
>     ...
>     extras_require={
>         'PDF':  ["ReportLab>=1.2", "RXP"],
>         'reST': ["docutils>=0.3"],
>     } )
> ```